# Не могу понять, как установить модуль

Tags: python, windows, cmd, python-2.x

Как установить модуль на Python 2.7.11? При введении:

```
$ pip install chatbot
```

мне выдает это:

> pip install chatbot
>    File "", line 1
>
> pip install chatbot
>    SyntaxError: invalid syntax  _

Немножко побродив в Интернете, я нашел, что надо устанавливать модуль на cmd, но там тоже ничего не помогло http://prntscr.com/9ic2n3

Comment: Вы читали в документации к проекту? Можете указать вывод `python --version`?

Comment: Откуда вы эту строчку набираете? Из терминала?

Comment: Если `pip` не прописан в переменной окружения `path`, то нужно его или прописать там, или запускать его из папки `Python27\Scripts`. Если он вообще не установлен, то его еще и установить нужно.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Вам нужно набрать
python setup.py install

Answer (score 4):

1.

```
pip install chatbot
File "", line 1

pip install chatbot
SyntaxError: invalid syntax _
```

Вы запускаете pip в консоли Python - этого делать не нужно, его нужно запускать из cmd.

2.

> "pip" не является внутренней или внешней программой ...

Попробуйте запустить его через полный путь: `C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe`
Если запустится, значит он установлен, просто не прописан в переменной окружения `path` (эту тему я опущу, вы с легкостью найдете информацию по этой теме с помощью поисковика).

Если не запустится, смотрите инструкцию по установке например здесь: [Устанавливаем python-пакеты с помощью pip](http://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pip.html) (Единственно, везде где там написано pip3, вам нужно писать просто pip, так как у вас Pyhton2, а не Python3)

3.

> ImportError: No module named requests

Через `python setup.py install` вы установили только пакет `chatbot` без зависимостей (нужных ему для запуска пакетов).

Если устанавливать через `pip`, то он сам скачает и установит вам и сам пакет, и его зависимости. Командная строка в вашем случае должна выглядеть так:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install chatbot
```

Но так как у вас этот модуль уже установлен, `pip`, возможно, откажется устанавливать его заново (ну или предложит добавить `-u` в командную строку для обновления модуля, тогда, возможно, установятся зависимости. В общем, пробуйте, экспериментируйте.)

Для практики попробуйте установить теперь модуль `requests` (на отсутствие которого ругается python) с помощью `pip`:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install requests
```

Если `chatbot` при импортировании ругнется на отсутствие других пакетов, установите и их.

Comment: `pip` и так доступен в Python 2.7.11 (`python -m pip`)

Comment: @IlmarMakkonen, не знаю где у тебя красным становится, нужно в cmd вставлять.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по ошибке вы запускаете интерпретатор Python из консоли и уже в него пытаетесь вбить команду `pip install chatbot`, на что он в ответ резонно ругается на некорректный синтаксис.

`pip` это отдельная утилита для установки пакетов в Python. Открываете консоль и сразу вбиваете `pip install chatbot`.

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо установить модуль request.
Скачивается и ставится точно также.
Но лучше конечно освоить pip.
Вначале скачиваете pip, распаковываете, устанавливаете.

```
python setup.py install
```

А потом уже с помощью pip устанавливаете все модули.

```
Pip install "modul_name"
```

Comment: @IlmarMakkonen, "Expected an indented block" - это значит, что перед def нужно было добавить отступ (таб).