# Не работает pip install в Python консоли

Tags: python, pip, syntax

Вроде ошибка в интернете есть, но попробовал решить - не помогло. Код:

```
>>> pip install
```

Ошибка:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Что делать? С путём всё нормально вроде.

Comment: Поделитесь кодом, который вызывает ошибку

Comment: >>> pip install
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>

Comment: Как я понял код `pip install`?

Comment: да,всё делаю в командной строке, но всё равно не работает

Comment: django пытаюсь установить

Comment: `pip install Django`

Comment: я так и написал....

Comment: Вы пару минут назад сказали, что код вызывающий ошибку `pip install`, судя по трейсбэку - ошибка в синтаксисе, но уверяю вас, если бы вы написали `pip install Django`, то ошибку в синтаксисе не выдало бы. PS. Вы это писали в IDE, а не в cmd. По крайней мере не в винде

Comment: Я зашел в пуск, написал cmd зашел,написал python , написал pip install django , не в какой IDE я не заходил

Comment: так вы не пишите в `cmd` `python` пишите там `pip install`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не могу понять, как установить модуль](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477898/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c)

Answer (score 15):

В Вашей строке вижу:

```
>>> pip install ...
```

Так понимаю, Вы запускаете в интерактивном режиме python (сам так первый раз запустил). `pip` запускается из командной строки Вашей ОС.

Запускаем `cmd`, пишем `pip install ...` и <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: я из командной строки запустил!!!!

Comment: @АнтонВасиленко если судить по ошибке указанной в вопросе - нет, вы запускали pip install в интерактивном режиме python. То что у вас просто в cmd не запускался pip (то что я вижу в вашем ответе) нигде не сказано. Поэтому по сути ответ правильный.

Answer (score 5):

А вас нечего не смущает? Что допустим ошибка не характерна для cmd.exe.

Решение:

Заходишь в cmd.exe и пишешь

```
>>>cd путь_к_python\Scripts
>>>pip install модуль который вы хотите установить
```

А вы зачем то вызываете команду для cmd с консоли python...

Answer (score 1):

не уверен, но

```
python -m pip install SomePackage
```

https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html#basic-usage

---

если не ошибаюсь, с третьей версии питона используется конструкция вида

```
python -m `имя модуля`
```

например

```
python -m http.server 8000
```

посмотреть версию

```
python -V
```

---

в третьем питоне создать виртуальное окружение и установить в него пакет

по шагам, проверено в линуксе, в винде, предположительно, отличаются только первые два шага

создать директорию

```
mkdir test
```

перейти в неё

```
cd test
```

создать окружение

```
python3 -m venv .env
```

зайти в него

```
source .env/bin/activate
```

установить пакет

```
python -m pip install django
```

окружение будет находиться в директории `.env`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47196099/4794368 - а тут можно почитать как это всё объединить с VSCode

Answer (score 1):

если 3я версия python, то в cmd попробуйте `pip3 install "название библиотеки"`

Answer (score 0):

### Для Windows

1. <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
2. Ввести `cmd` и нажать <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
3. Ввести команду и нажать <kbd>ENTER</kbd>:

```
>>> pip install название_пакета
```

### Для Linux или macOS

1. Открыть терминал.
2. Ввести команду и нажать <kbd>ENTER</kbd>:

```
>>> pip install название_пакета
```

> `>>>` это приглашение, оно может быть разное, например: `C:\>`, `$` или `#`.

Answer (score -1):

Короче нашел вот такой код: 
    `python -m pip install -U pip`
видимо pip у меня не был установлен(или обновлен) и это помогло.
а уже потом pip install django сработало
всё это нужно делать в командной строке