# как установить prettytable

Tags: python, pip, prettytable

Не могу установить `prettytable`. Запускаю *Python*. Далее: `pip install -U prettytable`  и получаю ошибку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Устанавливать надо не из питона. Если у вас `Anaconda`, то устанавливать из `Anaconda prompt`, а так вообще просто из системы устанавливайте.

Comment: Не нужно запускать Python. Запускаете cmd, в нем `pip install -U prettytable`

Comment: а что такое cmd?

Comment: пока только просто питон, анаконду думаю

Comment: @сергей *cmd* - командная строка. `Win + R` и в отрывшемся окне пишете `cmd`, потом `Enter`

Comment: пишет pip не является командой?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не работает pip install в Питон консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/792697/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-pip-install-%d0%b2-%d0%9f%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8)

Answer (score 2):

Вы выполняете команду `pip install -U prettytable` в самом интерпритаторе *Python*.
Вместо этого выполните ее в командной строке, запущенной от имени администратора.

Если же в командной строке у вас напишет, что команды pip не существует, то пропишите команду: `python -m pip install prettytable`.  Однако в данном случае я советую вам переустановить python, и при повторной установке прописать Python в PATH.

Comment: а как прописать Python в PATH?

Comment: @сергей, во время установки Python установите галочку у надписи "Add Python to PATH"

Answer (score 1):

Используй `pip install prettytable`, так написано на [странице библиотеки на PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/prettytable/) это в качестве альтернативы

### P.s выполняйте эту команду не в интерпретаторе Python, в командной строке (желательно с правами администратора)