# Проблема с системой управления пакетами pip

Tags: python

Хотел написать бота для телегам. Скачал снова питон, а тут такой сюрприз... Что не напишу связанное с pip - не работает.

> ```
> pip install --upgrade pip
> ```

Ошибка:

> ```
> File "<stdin>", line 1
>     pip install --upgrade pip
>               ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Comment: это ошибка в pycharm?

Comment: Нужно писать в консоли операционной системы, не в интерпретаторе Питона.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не могу понять, как установить модуль](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477898/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c)